# Change textarea inside webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, browser

I'm trying for hours to change a text area inside a webbrowser in VB.net. I was not able to do it... This is the code from that textarea :

```
<textarea name="message_html" class="textCtrl MessageEditor BbCodeWysiwygEditor " id="ctrl_message_html" style="height: 260px; display: none;" data-options='{"autoSaveFrequency":"60","bbCodes":[]}' data-auto-save-url="forums/Snapchat-Girls/save-draft" data-dialog-url="index.php?editor/dialog&amp;style=1" data-css-url="css.php?style=1&amp;css=editor_contents&amp;d=1447310869">&lt;p&gt;This is where the text will be&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
```

Note : Loog for "This is where the text will be" inside the code.

Codes i tried :

```
    For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If element.OuterHtml.Contains("textCtrl MessageEditor") Then
            element.SetAttribute("value", "TEST")
        End If
    Next

   WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctrl_message_html").SetAttribute("value","TEST")

    For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All
         element.SetAttribute("value", "TEST")
    Next
```

None of these worked...

PS : Is not my website. So don't ask me to add ids or something.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is not needed anymore, but for reference to those who might still be looking for an answer to this question....maybe this might help your needs

Dim Wctl as string = WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Replace("[searchvalue1]", "test1").Replace("[searchvalue2]", "test2")

Then

WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "0" 
WebBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(True) 
WebBrowser1.Document.Write(Wctl) 
WebBrowser1.Refresh()